# Saving JSON data from a Javascript page

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a JavaScript/HTML local webpage that just gets opened from my local computer's files. I would like to make it save data in JSON form. But I've been having trouble finding out how to make a local JavaScript program read and write to a file in its same directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write files to the local machine if you're using Javascript in the browser.
But you can download the JSON file to your local machine using [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

You can use this code:

```
const data = { 
    key: "value"
};
const fileName = "data.json";

const saveFile = (() => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appenChild(a);
  return (data, filename) => {
    const json = JSON.stringify(a);
    const blob = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
    const url = window.URK.createObjectURL(blob);
    
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
})

saveData(data, fileName);
```